# Allow Connection From WAN to LAN

Tags: networking, router, firewall, lan, wan

I have made a Web Server using Python Socket which I can reach with in my LAN but not reachable from the WAN. I have enabled 'Virtual Server' in my router. I think the router's Firewall is blocking it, so I tried to find any settings but I don't know where find and what to do. I am Using Router: D-link DIR-615 | Hardware version: T3 | Firmware Version: 20.22 .

- My Problem: Maybe I have to allow WAN connection to my LAN but I don't know how to do.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: [Fastest D-Link DIR-615 Router Port Forwarding Guide](https://portforward.com/d-link/dir-615/)

Answer (score 1):

Just going off of what you said:

Your firewall is maybe not fully set up to do port forwarding to your private server. For security reasons, you will want to ensure that inbound traffic on the web ports (80/443) are forwarded to the IP of your webserver only. Youll also need your router set up with a NAT loopback policy unless you want to test your webserver on a client using a mobile phone or a hotspot. I am not sure what checking the virtual server box on your router does exactly, but, it may be something to look into and compare it to the steps i am about to provide.

Here is a link for all the steps required to open up a server to the world. Its on a different router, but the overall concepts should be the same.

https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-enable-port-forwarding-and-allow-access-to-a-server-through-the-sonicwall/170503477349850/

Comment: From within your network - Are you on a LAN device and using the private IP address of your webserver? Using Public IP - are you on a LAN device and using your router's public IP? Or are you trying from a non-internal-network device such as a mobile phone without Wifi?